# Check differently nested properties in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Is there a way to implement the Postgres equivalent to CHECK constraint within a nested JSON Schema? Say we have data that has two properties, each of which has nested properties. How can JSON Schema make the required contents of the first object depend on the second?

My real case scenario is to build a JSON schema for a GeoJSON objects, that has a geometry object (i.e. Point or Polygon, or null), and other attributes in a "properties" object. I want to alter the required properties depending on the type of geometry.

I failed with both the following solutions:

- Nest "allOf" inside "anyOf" to cover all the possibilities
- Duplicate the "definitions" to have a attributes_no_geom, geometry_no_geom, attribute_with_geom and geometry_with_geom and declare them in a "anyOf"

This would validate since attribute/place covers for the lack of geometry:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "name": "Person2",
        "place": "City2"
    },
    "geometry": null
}
```

This would also validate since  attribute/place is no longer required with a geometry:

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "name": "Person1"
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point", 
        "coordinates": []
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Building on Relequestual's answer, this is the unsatisfactory result I'm getting :

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "geometryIsPoint": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["type"],
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "const": "Point"
        }
      }
    },
    "partialAttributes": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["name"],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "place": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "fullAttributes": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["name", "place"],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "place": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "conditionalAttributes": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/geometryIsPoint"
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/partialAttributes"
          },
          "else": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/fullAttributes"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "attributes": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/conditionalAttributes"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/geometryIsPoint"
    }
  }
}
```

This schema will not validate the following if the `attributes/place` property is removed.

```
{
    "attributes": {
        "name": "Person",
        "place": "INVALID IF THIS LINE IS REMOVED ;-("
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point", 
        "coordinates": {}
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the `if/then/else` keywords, wrapped inside an `allOf` to achive what you want here. I hope to provide you with a fuller answer sometime today.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a library that supports draft-7 JSON Schema. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I'm using draft-7 JSON Schema. Thank you for the suggestion. I will give conditionals a try but my understanding of the docs was that the content of the conditional blocks always refered to the properties they were declared in, therefore, in the example above, I could not do something like `if geometry/type then require something in attributes`?

Comment: It IS possible. I'll show you how soon =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`if/then/else` keywords](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.6) to apply subschemas conditionally.

We only want `if` and `then` for your solution.

The value of both must be a JSON Schema.

If the value of `if` results in a positive assertion (when the schema is applied to the instance, and it validates successfully), then the schema value of `then` is applied to the instance.

Here's the schema.

I've pre-loaded the schema and data at [https://jsonschema.dev](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEASMBjAFgUwLYCGqkKI2ALhQA6QD0dAVmAPbwC0WeRAdCwE4BzOgBN+hAGYV2ABgDsdLgUIBiVABoEyVCNwSAlvH0V9bMCURwkyMoNwt8uCvwCeASTAAFFoYoWrNjao-LgAjgCu+iEiFgDaWoFBIBQu1LioCYEAuprWgajU-Cxp-Ca45lCWmYmoKWn+1YlkmGZ+lajevhl5iQC+jYj9Pb25+SB2Dk6uAIJePvBtpAE1ICERUbgxlfE9Yy0CIoaEFOXdTTkDBUUlZRVLA9og+-yH8MenlctNj3Xp7SCEfjiFxnb5DJrgmwjaqoCaOZwgz6XAEAGxRAHkJHEHlVdit9FikXimqg0CFCaRUCpRHpDMZTPAwHQ4VN3HMuiAcchocSkhQ8PAGryxmS9BYqTSDEYTGZmfZ4TN2QtQd9BjjIdlqpCeY9CsVcKV9B97j1YfLWUKSehyeKQNTdFL6bKWQiVWrrENeiB1CB9FAYDCAVR+PoAEbhE53XGq1BvRy2zwG1jwACMbp1SRdrkt31qqT+lJAnWV3pQvNQz1e7yjwA17q9vSAA) so you can test it live.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "geometryIsPoint": {
      "required": [
        "type"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "const": "Point"
        }
      }
    },
    "geometryAsPoint": {
      "required": [
        "coordinates"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "coordinates": {
          "type": "array"
        }
      }
    },
    "geometry": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/geometryIsPoint"
          },
          "then": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/geometryAsPoint"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "geometry": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/geometry"
    }
  }
}
```

The property `geometry` references the definition `geometry`.

`allOf` is an array of schemas.

The value of `allOf[0].if` references the schema defined as `geometryIsPoint`.

The schema defined as `geometryIsPoint` is applied to the `geometry` value. If it validates successfully, then the `then` referenced schema is applied.

You don't have to use referencing to do any of this, but I feel it makes the intent clearer.

Extend the schema as required, adding schemas to `allOf` for as many geometry types as you want to recognise.

---

Edit:

You were hitting the `else` condition of your conditional, because the `if` failed validation. Let me explain.

Here's an updated schema to cover your modified use case.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "geometry": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "type"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "enum": [
            "Point",
            "somethingelse",
            null
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "geometryIsPoint": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "type"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "type": {
          "const": "Point"
        }
      }
    },
    "attributes": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "place": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    },
    "partialAttributes": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name"
      ]      
    },
    "fullAttributes": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "place"
      ]
    },
    "conditionalAttributes": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "required": [
              "geometry"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "geometry": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/geometryIsPoint"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "required": [
              "attributes"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "attributes": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/partialAttributes"
              }
            }
          },
          "else": {
            "required": [
              "attributes"
            ],
            "properties": {
              "attributes": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/fullAttributes"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "attributes": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/attributes"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/geometry"
    }
  },
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/conditionalAttributes"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's a [JSON Schema dev link](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEASMBjAFgUwLYCGqkKI2ALhQA6QD0dAVmAPbwC0WeRAdCwE4BzOgBN+hAGYV2ABgDsdLgUIBiVABoEyVCNwSAlvH0V9bMCURwkyMoNwt8uCvwCeFqzZuoKL6rguoLABGjLiYFBpanmT8uACOAK76sSIWANpR0WQ+fqiZNgC6mtaeqNT8LH78JrjmUJb5pSA5-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-tmiC5kBNLIXG85TFBv7whySJcqhAkgWRKF7mhqAYceZDYeeeH1mAdARlG3EstRyAvnqb6koGFZRO+MGrvBxpIaBPFSZ0slYWeuGXvAKniTaVkVtSVz2LOu72u6tkpiACkOfhTnXl5O7zhSxntts3aAcgCEyUedk4ReIUqdWtYhSRGkUVR1j7PAhwTIOUAwOZLnkaJTQCgWBJDEirDfoWvogAAcp2AAqiBDAAMhaADCACi4p3G1ABqFq9XcAAiiB3AAYognUABJ3AAyog01tUN82bQASkNACynbjUNc0ANzsAAFJFHk3nO1kQsmBIdd1QydmNnUaCgrW4gItYClZPKGqcxWHEAA) so you can test it.

What we're doing here is splitting up the concerns.

The "shape" of `attributes` and `geometry` is defined in definitions with the corresponding key. Those schemas do not assert which keys are required in those objects, only what they must be if provided.

Because `$ref` in a schema makes all other keywords in a schema ignored (for draft-7 or below), at the root level, I've wrapped the reference to `conditionalAttributes` in an `allOf`.

`conditionalAttributes` is a defined JSON Schema. I've used `allOf` so you can add more conditional checks.

The value of `conditionalAttributes.allOf[0].if` is a JSON Schema, and is applied to the root of your JSON instance. It requires a key of `geometry` and that the value is `geometryIsPoint`. (If you omit the `required`, you'll end up with validation issues, because omitting that key will then pass the if condition).

When the instance results in a `true` assertion (validation valid) for the `if` value schema, then the `then` value schema is applied at the root level.

Because it's applied at the root level and you want to check the value of a nested property, you have to use `properties` as you would if you were at the root level of your schema. **THIS** is how you do conditional schema application (`if/then/else`) across different depths of your instance.

You can test out the conditional resolution by changing one of the schema values to `false` and looking at the errors. Remember, `true` and `false` are valid JSON Schemas, so you can write `"then": false` to cause an error if you expect the `then` schema to be applied (as in, the `if` schema asserted validation OK).

Comment: This is a really nice example of how to use the `if/then` keywords. May end up copying it to the site.

Comment: Thank you for your very useful input and work on JSON Schema! Unfortunately, I have not yet managed to make it work while referencing properties outside of the geometry property, that is the geometry/type property that should modify the requirement of attributes/place

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for your update. It's best if you update your question to show new requirements. I can help you solve this problem also.

Comment: Updated. There's a lot there, including how conditional applicability works. Let me know if you have any further questions or comments =]

Comment: Brilliant, this works and answers my initial concern ! Still a long way to go, but conditionnal requirements isn't an issue anymore :)

Comment: Glad I could help! If you want to buy me a coffee, please see the link on my profile =]