# Conditional JSON schema based on dynamic property value

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm trying to validate a JSON file that contains several nested components of the same type. Each component has a `class` string property. I'm trying to apply different validation schemas from my definitions to each component based on the value of `class`. Furthermore, the values of *class* can be "button-open", "button-close", "icon-message", "icon-...", "container", etc and I would like to apply the same validation schema for all the "buttons-" another to "icons-" and another to the rest.

The code I provide is what I have tried. I have excluded `icons-` for the shake of simplicity. As you can see I tried to match with a regular expression whenever there is `button` in `class`. Then it should constraint the minimum value of children elements to 1.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["results"],
    "properties": {
        "results": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "anyOf": [
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/genericComponent"
                    },
                    {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/button"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "genericComponent": {
            "type": "object",
            "$id": "#/definitions/genericComponent",
            "required":[
                "class",
                "children"
            ],
            "properties":{
                "class": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "description": "predicted class of the element(img, icon..)"
                },
                "children":{
                    "type": "array",
                    "description": "this element can contain more of the same type",
                    "items":{
                        "type": "object",
                        "anyOf":[
                            {"$ref": "#/definitions/button"},
                            {"$ref": "#/definitions/genericComponent"}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "button": {
            "$id": "#/definitions/button",
            "allOf":[
                {"$ref": "#/definitions/genericComponent"},
                {"properties": {
                    "class":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "pattern": "(button)"
                    },
                    "children":{
                        "type": "array",
                        "description": "this element must contain one generic element",
                        "items":{
                            "type": "object",
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/genericComponent"
                        },
                        "minItems": 1,
                        "maxItems": 1
                    }
                }}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried to apply the property conditionally as:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["results"],
    "properties": {
        "results": {
            "type": "array",
            "minItems": 1,
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "$ref": "#/definitions/genericComponent"
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "genericComponent": {
            "type": "object",
            "$id": "#/definitions/genericComponent",
            "required":[
                "class",
                "children"
            ],
            "properties":{
                "class":{
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "children":{
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "anyOf":[
                            {"$ref":"#/definitions/genericComponent"},
                            {"$ref":"#/definitions/button"}
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },  
            "if": {
                "properties": {"class": {"pattern": "^button-rect$"}}
            },
            "then": {
                "properties": {
                    "children":{
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/genericComponent"
                         },
                         "minItems": 1,
                    }
                }
            },
            "else": {
                "properties": {
                    "children":{
                        "type": "array",
                        "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/genericComponent"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: this one sample that pass but it shouldn't as the number of children of one of the buttons is highier of 1.

```
{"results": [
  {
    "class": "box",
    "children": [
      {
        "class": "icon",
        "children": []
      },
      {
        "class": "button-rect",
        "children": [
          {
            "class": "label",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "class": "button-round",
        "children": [
          {
            "class": "label",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "class": "label",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

Comment: Hi Arturo. I answered a very similar question today here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054781/check-differently-nested-properties-in-json-schema I can't flag this question as a duplicate because the answer is so new. Let me know if reading that answer doesn't help.

Comment: It is slightly different as in that question the number of possible values is finite (Point, Polygon and null). In my case, there is an unlimited number and I would like to apply one schema for everything that contains "button"("button-open", "button-close",...) another for the ones that contain "icon" and another for the rest.

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track using `pattern`. Can you provide example JSON instance data you expect to pass and fail (and explain why) please? Then I might be able to help further. =]

Comment: sure! I updated the question with a sample that passes but it shouldn't

Comment: Near to having the answer for you. Are you interested as to why your first approach didn't work? You are much closer with your second approach (and that's the way I'd approach it anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of applying conditionally was close, but had a few errors.

The reference for `#/definitions/button` couldn't be resolved, so you might have seen an error.

The regex you used in your if condition was for `button-rect` while you asked for it to cover `button-round` in your example. You could of course change it to a non anchored `^button-` which sounds like what you want.

Here's the schema.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": [
    "results"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "results": {
      "type": "array",
      "minItems": 1,
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "$ref": "#/definitions/genericComponent"
      }
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "genericComponent": {
      "type": "object",
      "$id": "#/definitions/genericComponent",
      "required": [
        "class",
        "children"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "class": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "children": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/genericComponent"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "class": {
                "pattern": "^button-round$"
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "properties": {
              "children": {
                "maxItems": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The `then` schema is applied to the instance. You don't need to repeat the constraints already expressed by the other part of that schema (with the `$id` of `#/definitions/genericComponent`). And by extension, you don't need the `else` either. (This isn't the same as writing code with an execution flow.)

You can see this schema in action against your JSON instance data at [https://jsonschema.dev](https://jsonschema.dev/s/N4IgziBcLAOgdgAkbEAXAngBwKasiiAPYBGAVjgMZqoA0CyqATjgI4CuAliwCb6IBtBskIsw7ADZowqYQF16SQliZFcTNJxwyoiOEsYgxk6f30iRqTLn6oAhkyZ2MdYRdQBbTvACSaHB46BACMihaGnP6BZm7hVth4uqikFNSuBnEgACQsAGa2IADEAPQ8OLnekZxE8GDFAOY48DhMnJQAwkQeWDVNNCCxyAC+sSNKQ2GEZRXwVTVBerGojc2tHV09zfD9BOaZ1okEyeRU-ZPu2Zx8SUWl5ZWa8w1NLW2d3b3b6eGibFy8-CEGQulAkdjAOnOmUoAAtOBIeCx4LJgYgFINlKp1JptDFUYZQeCFnsfoYDgUwGhWvB6ijSYgJhiCXCEUi8fSyQkCg4nC4QFCfqhIgFiUz9lybilTt8OYY7PAMAB5fK6IGyiwk9WGHLlAolaYPaq1Z6rN4bT79MU-MZauRWhlim3hRmo+wSCTKwFizWCkCcFW7e2GFRqFo40X40moQkQ9laywgLB2ND+JjIm4APRI7BTNQAtKp2PAeFk6fGnbKK6SXbKrDCmnHa4msWGtBH44RYfDEQ3dD71Z47AAPPwi-jBIMiKv06fOx0Yu0ZJ1jIb8v1QGDCZjaEwLNUifvRsGxm4kIhDmUglk99MEfc-fsg48LIWUGqXqMgLus3t3xczgUD3tI8iQKbNc3gAtpX5YCv2vNlVUnR9PxjF8QDBEgcAkD8m2-G9AX-dVZwsQjrUA5BkIJZ8wJzNB80LYscOheDf0EJDJyo0CbgwrCmPpaMWNvQRSI5Gt1Uo6FqO4uxMOwmDI19PCEL-SdiJEESLFnESnUXVchiAA) (link is preloaded with your schema and data)

Let me know if you have any questions. There are a number of issues with the first approach, but given this is the better approach, I'm not sure "fixing" the first one is in scope of this question. =]

Comment: Thanks, Relequetual! This schema is valid. In the beginning, it was still not working and found out that the python jsonschema module did not support this solution for version 2.6. With the latest, it's working fine :)