# validate nested content of json schema

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I’m creating a schema consists of multiple categories. In each category there’s an array of key:value pairs. Each key represents the display name of value. Each value is unique and can only be assigned to a single key and category.

As an example, a category called ‘primates’ will have ‘human’ as one of the key/ display name, and the biological name ‘Homo sapiens’ will be the corresponding value of the key:value pair.

I want to validate data entry so that data matches with only one of the key/ display name. I put `anyOf` for the categories, does it do the same job? Is this how you will arrange items in the schema?

```
 {
  "$schema": "https://example.com/schema/dictionary",
  "$id": "https://example.com/schemaoutput/dictionary",
  "description": "A schema that validates the minimum requirements for validation output",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "subcat1": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "category1",
        "tag": [
          {
            "display_labelA": [
              "class_A"
            ],
            "display_labelB": [
              "class_B"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "subcat2": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "category2",
        "tag": [
          {
            "display_labelC": [
              "class_C"
            ],
            "display_labelD": [
              "class_D"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "anyOf": [
      {
        "required": [
          "subcat1",
          "subcat2"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Edit:

As requested I updated the post with expected pass and fail scenarios. For example I want to create a json schema containing different categories of animals in the animal kingdom. Each key:value pair refer to the commonly known animal name and the corresponding scientific name. Only data entries of animals' commonly known names will be accepted.

Pass scenarios:

1. A data entry ‘human’ will be accepted, since it is one of the key:value pair (human: Homo sapiens) of category ‘primates’.

2. A data entry ‘chimpanzee’ will also be accepted. It is also one of the key:value pair (chimpanzee: pan troglodytes) of category ‘primates’.
3. A data entry ‘salmon’ will be accepted. Its key:value pair (Salmon: Salmo salar Linnaeus) is located in another category ‘fish’.

Fail scenarios:

1. Any data entry that are not listed in the animal kingdom dictionary will not be accepted e.g. Pear, Oranges, Table, Chairs…

Comment: I'm not quite following this. Could you provide some example JSON instances that show cases that should pass and cases that should fail?

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers Sorry it wasn’t clear, I guess I was clouded when I wrote the question as I’m still very new to this. I updated with a few expected pass and fail scenarios.

Comment: I'm afraid this still doesn't make sense. I suspect that you are trying to get JSON Schema to do something that JSON Schema doesn't do. You have a schema that describes an array of categories. You can use that schema to validate that an array of categories is structured correctly. It seems like you want to validate that a string, such as "human", is in the array of categories. You actually want to validate against the instance somehow, not the schema. That's my best understanding of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @JasonDesrosiers yes what you suspected is something I want to do - to validate strings that exist in the defined dictionary. I know json schema can set range of numeric values and data types for validation, but in my case I want to validate string data entry. i start to think if this question put in the link something I need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57076320/conditional-json-schema-based-on-dynamic-property-value?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: I added the answer here - the json structure is valid but keen to know if this is logical/ what you have in mind @JasonDesrosiers

Answer (score 0):

Looking through [1](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/index.html) and other posts I think `enum` is what I need to map key:value pairs (i.e. biological name:commonly known name) under each category (primates or fish). I'm using `anyOf` at the end of the JSON schema to validate data entry that contain any values specified under any category.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://example.com/schema/dictionary",
    "$id": "https://example.com/schemaoutput/dictionary",
    "description": "A schema that validates the minimum requirements for validation output",
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
            "subcat1": {
                "type": "string",
                "title": "category1",
                "enum": [{
                    "display_labelA": "class_A",
                    "display_labelB": "class_B"
                }]
            },
            "subcat2": {
                "type": "string",
                "title": "category2",
                "enum": [{
                    "display_labelA": "class_A",
                    "display_labelB": "class_B"
                }]
            }
        },
        "anyOf": [{
            "required": [
                "subcat1",
                "subcat2"
            ]
        }]
    }
}
```